# Triangle Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've just graduated as an undergraduate in statistics. My girlfriend presented a problem to me today after she was finished with a crochet project.

She has created 80 crocheted triangles, each of which contains 6 non-repeating colors in a random order. There are 10 possible colors.

She wanted me to find the probability that there exists a pair of triangles that contain the same color pattern (order does matter).

How would you approach this problem? (Please state your assumptions.) If I have to, I'll have to run a simulation on Python to get a good value.

Comment: Could you add a drawing or something? I don't understand how the triangles are colored or arranged

Comment: Is the triangular shape relevant?  Or are we just talking about selecting $6$ different items, in order, from $10$ possibilities?

Comment: @David, that assumption can be made for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Here is an example of a triangle: consider colors A, B, ... , F. A crocheted triangle is a right triangle consisting of 6 different colors (starting from the outside and going inward): color A with 12 nodes, color B with 10 nodes, color C with 8 nodes, color D with 6 nodes, color E with 4 nodes, color F with 2 nodes (placed at the center of the hypotenuse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of the pattern don't really matter in this case, from your comment it seems clear that all we are really doing is selecting $6$ different items from $10$ possibilities, with order important.  The number of ways to do this is
$$P(10,6)=10\times9\times8\times7\times6\times5=151200\ .$$
If we make $80$ such choices, the probability that they are all different is
$$\frac{P(151200)}{151200^{80}}$$
and the probability that you get two or more with the same pattern is $1$ minus this, which comes to $0.0207$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense (that the original structure of the triangle doesn't matter).

Comment: In a different question it might matter.  Say the six colours were at the vertices and midpoints of an equilateral triangle, and that the triangle can be rotated through $120^\circ$ in either direction.  Then the choice of colours ROYGBI would be the same as YGBIRO, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that only the colours used matter, not the pattern that they form.

There are $\binom{10}{6}$ equally likely choices of $6$ colours. This is a smallish number, $210$.

The probability that if you make $80$ "at random" they will all be distinct is virtually $0$. Please see Wikipedia, the [Birthday Problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

**Remark:** The exact probability they are all distinct is 
$$\frac{210}{210}\cdot\frac{209}{210}\cdot\frac{208}{210}\cdots \cdot\frac{131}{220}.$$

If pattern matters, then one would have to know the details of the pattern. If the pattern consists of many coloured subtriangles, then the probability of a collision among $80$ objects will be very small.

Comment: Good, this is how I thought of it at first. I'm wondering if anyone will be brave enough to try this problem out using the actual format of the triangles (see my last comment).

Comment: From the clarification in the OP's comment I believe the intention is that order **does** matter.

Comment: It could be thought of as a clarification, or as a change.

Comment: Well, as far as I saw, the third paragraph of the OP always said clearly that order does matter.  Though I would agree that the use of the word "random" in the second paragraph is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume the triangles can be moved through $R^3$ freely I shall assume the triangles are $10$-ary [bracelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29#Number_of_bracelets) of length $6$.

There are $$\frac{11(10^{3})}{4}+\frac{1}{12}\sum_{d|6}\phi(d)10^{(6/d)}=86185$$

There are $\binom{86185}{80}$ ways to select $80$ different triangles out of $86185$. Using stars and bars there are $\binom{86185+79}{79}$ ways to select how many of each type you want if you have $80$ triangles and $86185$ types.

Therefore the probability you want is:

$$\dfrac{\binom{86185}{80}}{\binom{86184+80}{80}}\approx .93$$

So the probability all of them are different is approximately $93\%$